# Making `TStaticText` transparent

Tags: delphi, transparency, window-handles

I have to use `TStaticText` instead of `TLabel` to make my software friendly to screen-readers because `TStaticText` has window handle and `TLabel` does not.

However, even though `TStaticText` has `Transparent` property, it is not really transparent on a gradient background.

Can anyone recommend way how to make it transparent or perhaps how to make a simple custom component which would be compatible with screen readers (having window handle that is) and be transparent at the same time?

Comment: I guess you need to override default handling of `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`.

Comment: You might be better to make a TLabel derivative that was friendly to automation. That way you'd know how to do same for other non Win32 controls. It does astonish me that VCL (and presumably FMX) still doesn't support automation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually FMX has support for Accessibility - look here - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/FireMonkey_Accessibility_Package . How would you go about making TLable friendly to automation?

Comment: Wow, a rare win for FMX! ;-) There's a really good answer here on SO from Remy Lebeau on the subject of adding accessibility to a vcl control. A search should yield it. Or find Remy's top answers.

Comment: Ok, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320914/creating-accessible-ui-components-in-delphi/16322828#16322828

Comment: Windows needs to have themes enabled for the transparency of TStaticText to work.