# How to set the Accessible Name associated with a TEdit control?

Tags: delphi, accessibility, delphi-xe6, uiaccessibility

If a user is using a screen reader (e.g. Microsoft Narrator), and their focus enters a text box:

[image]

All they hear is:

> *Editing text*

Meanwhile in accessible applications,

- such as Microsoft File Explorer
- Microsoft Word
- Microsoft Excel
- Microsoft Outlook

the accessibility system is able to get the control's *"Accessible Name"*:

[image]

> *Batch separator. Editing text*

This works though the window implementing the [**IAccessible**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface. It obtains a window's implementation of **IAccessible** by sending the hWnd the [**WM_GETOBJECT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message. Applications never send this message though:

> Sent by both Microsoft Active Accessibility and Microsoft UI Automation to obtain information about an accessible object contained in a server application.
>
> Applications never send this message directly. Microsoft Active Accessibility sends this message in response to calls to AccessibleObjectFromPoint, AccessibleObjectFromEvent, or AccessibleObjectFromWindow.

But we can *handle* the message, and return an **IAccessible** interface to the caller:

```
case Message.Msg of
WM_GETOBJECT: 
   begin
      if DWORD(Message.LParam) = OBJID_CLIENT then
         Message.Result := LResultFromObject(IAccessible, Message.WParam, FAccessible);
   end;
end;
```

In the .NET world, their wrapper around an [**Edit** control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx), exposes a way to set the *accessible name* of an TextBox using the [**Control.AccessibleName** property:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.accessiblename(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ### Control.AccessibleName Property
>
> Gets or sets the name of the control used by accessibility client applications.
>
> ```
> public string AccessibleName { get; set; }
> ```

I don't know how the underlying Microsoft Edit control exposes accessibility features. I couldn't find any reference to **IAccessible** in the VCL except for TCustomActionMenuBar.

How does the VCL expose accessibility features?

How do i set the Accessible Name associated with a TEdit control?

How do i set the Accessible Name associated with an Edit control?

### Bonus Chatter

The **name** of an accessible item is returned through the [read-only IAccessible.accName property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318483(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
Property  Access Type  Description
--------  -----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
accName   Read-only    The name of the object. All objects support this property.
                       See get_accName.
```

### Bonus Reading

- [Edit Control (MSAA UI Element Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318062(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Implement `IAccessible` interface by yourself (the Accessible Name you return in its `Get_accName` method).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How does the VCL expose accessibility features?

**It doesn't, at all.**

If you want this feature, you have to manually implement everything related to `IAccessible` yourself in your own code, and then subclass your VCL controls to respond to the `WM_GETOBJECT` message, just like you showed in your question.

For example:

[Creating Accessible UI components in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320914/)

Comment: AFAIK, currently only TActionBar implements this feature.